# Error: Cannot find module 'less'

Tags: node.js, module, less, dump, assetic

When running command: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\dule\AppData\Local\Temp\ass2560.tmp"` I got this error:

> Error Output:
>    module.js:339
>        throw err;
>        ^
>    Error: Cannot find module 'less'
>        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
>        at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
>        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
>        at require (module.js:385:17)
>        at Object. (C:\Users\dule\AppData\Local\Temp\ass2560.tmp:1:74)
>        at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
>        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
>        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>        at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
>        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to your problem is to run the command:

```
npm install -g less
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have less module installed and the path is correct as in attachment.[image]